# How to compare two Time objects only down to the hour

Tags: ruby

I want to compare two Time objects only down to the hour, while ignoring the difference of minutes and seconds.

I'm currently using `t0.strftime("%Y%m%d%H") == t1.strftime("%Y%m%d%H")`, but I don't think this is a good solution.

Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ActiveSupport (either through Rails, or just installed as a gem), it includes an [extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) to the `Time` class that adds a `change` method which will truncate times:

```
$> require "active_support/core_ext/time"
# => true
$> t = Time.now
# => 2014-03-07 21:30:01 -0500
$> t.change(hour: 0)
# => 2014-03-07 00:00:00 -0500
```

This won't modify the original time value either. So you can do this:

```
t0.change(minute: 0) == t1.change(minute: 0)
```

It'll zero out everything at a lower granularity (seconds, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick in pure Ruby

```
t0.to_a[2..9] == t1.to_a[2..9]
```

Where [Time#to_a](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/to_a)

```
$> Time.now.to_a
# => [7, 44, 2, 8, 3, 2014, 6, 67, false, "GMT"]
# [ sec, min, hour, day, month, year, wday, yday, isdst, zone ]
```

So you can check that the times are equals or not up to the level you want and without missing important components of the object like the zone, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time'

t1 = Time.new ; sleep 30 ; t2 = Time.new
t1.hour == t2.hour
```

This should give you a boolean answer.